# FabricCommon.dll not found when accessing actor service

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

Using Azure Service Fabric doing a demo example from Pluralsight im trying to remote to an actor service to get all actors like this.

```
   public IActorService GetUserActorService()
        {
            var proxy = ActorServiceProxy.Create(new Uri("fabric:/ECommerce/UserActor"), 0);
            return proxy;
        }
```

But i get these two errors:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FabricCommon.dll' or one of
>   its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.
>
> TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.Fabric.Common.AppTrace' threw an exception.

Comment: Did you install the SF SDK on your dev machine?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, it looks like something might not have installed properly. Try reinstalling the Azure SF SDK on the machine to see if it resolves the issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#sdk-installation-only

Comment: I just realised that i might have misunderstood how SF works. This code in the OP that gives this message is from a normal Console Application that references the Actor Service.But i just realised maybe a console application is not supposed to be able to access an actor service ?

Comment: Can you share the guide you are following?